# Setting Resolution Size in Java

Tags: java, swing

I am currently making my own version of a chess game in Java, and I created my own pixel art chess pieces using GIMP. However, I use Windows 10, and my screen resolution (1920 by 1080) is scaled by %150. This affects the Java output as well, and my pieces, which should be 50 by 62 pixels, are also scaled up by %150. When I find the screen resolution in Java, it says that my screen resolution is 1280 by 720. The ideal situation is for me to be able to run it with the right-sized pieces without manually changing my computer's resolution. Is there any way to force Java to run my program without it being scaled by Windows? I'm using Swing/JFrame for my application.

Comment: This looks like it might provide a hacky way forward by setting java system properties. Note it's not very simple to do in Java 8 and later: https://superuser.com/questions/988379/how-do-i-run-java-apps-upscaled-on-a-high-dpi-display > Or alternately you could try Java 8, which the question implies does what you want.

Comment: Yeah, I've tried that. But I think I'm trying to do the opposite. I want it to be a small, not blurry display that Windows doesn't try to scale up automatically.

Comment: Also, I have to share this project with others, so I'd prefer it to not require changing my system settings manually.

Comment: Yes you'd need to interpret that article in reverse. That's why I said roll back to Java 8. If that article is right, java didn't start honoring Windows scaling until Java 9.  Are you using Java 9?